# Fallbacks for renamed properties in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift4, xcode9

I am having trouble finding fallbacks for things like

```
UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName
NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor
```

This issue arises in Swift 4 within XCode 9. Currently, I have to do

```
#if swift(>=4.0)
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        ["NSColor": UIColor.white]
    }
 #else 
       [NSForegroundColorAttributeName.rawValue: UIColor.white]
```

But, for UIFontDescriptor I can't find anything that will work for iOS 8. Also if you can improve this hack that would be awesome as well.

Comment: This is really confusing. What are you attempting to do with this code?

Comment: @rmaddy Trying to find things that work for Swift 4, Xcode 9 but also are available in iOS 8. For example, say you want an attributedString on a UIBarItem. You call setTitleTextAttributes but you need to return a dictionary of [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] but NSAttributedStringKey was added in iOS 11. How would you do it for all iOS versions 8+.

Comment: If you are doing this a lot in your code, you could create your custom enum. Build a function which accepts this enum and converts it into a dictionary. Only the function would contain #if checks. This would be easier to change at a later date when there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you post an example

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 you use `UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.xxx` and `NSAttributedStringKey.yyy where`xxx`and`yyy` are the desired names.

In Swift 3 you use `UIFontDescriptorXXXAttribute` and `NSYYYAttributeName` where `XXX` and `YYY` are the desired names.

The Swift 4 code will work just fine as is for iOS 11, 10, 9, and 8 as long as the key you use existed back in iOS 8. You do not need the `#if` or the `#available`.

This means that the following code can be used in Xcode 9 for an app with a Deployment Target of iOS 8 or later:

```
let fontDesc = UIFontDescriptor()
fontDesc.addingAttributes([ .name: "Helvetica" ])
let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDesc, size: 14)
let dict = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green, NSAttributedStringKey.font: font ]
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: dict)
```

If you have some need to build this code with both Xcode 9 and Xcode 8 (Swift 4 and Swift 3), then you need to do:

```
let fontDesc = UIFontDescriptor()
#if swift(>=4.0)
    fontDesc.addingAttributes([ .name: "Helvetica" ])
#else
    fontDesc.addingAttributes([ UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute: "Helvetica" ])
#endif
let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDesc, size: 14)
#if swift(>=4.0)
    var dict = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow, NSAttributedStringKey.font: font ]
#else
    var dict = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow, NSFontAttributeName: font ]
#endif

let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: dict)
```

Note that in either set of code you do not use `rawValue` for any of the keys. And you should note hardcode the key strings. Use the provided constants.

Comment: In the docs say NSAttributedStringKey was added in iOS 11 but then all the properties are good for iOS 6 or older, does that mean as long as I use the property its ok?

Comment: Yes, `NSAttributedStringKey` was added in iOS 11 but the values they represent are equal to the corresponding values from the previous API. This is why you can use `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` in Xcode 9 and have it work in older versions of iOS. At runtime it is the same value. Use the first set of code I posted and it will work. I tested that code in the iOS 8 simulator and I could see the colored, Helvetica text.